# If $x^2-5x+1=0$ what is value of $\frac{x^{10}+1}{x^5}$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If $x^2-5x+1=0$ what is value of  $\frac{x^{10}+1}{x^5}$.

I tried with calculator but I don't think that,that was proper method ,if you got one pls post it

Comment: Find $x$ on base of equality and substitute.

Comment: You mean root of that equation , that's irrational dude,send me that lengthy calculation you would make to get that to 10th power

Comment: I need mathematical method not calculative

Comment: For a light hint, there is an algebraic method here which exploits the symmetry in the coefficients. You should perhaps try to find it. And there are other ways of proceeding too, which will get you there in the end. Now you know there is an algebraic method, maybe you will have the confidence to try to find it?

Comment: $x+\frac1x=5$.  Square that to find $x^2+\frac1{x^2}$ and so on up to $x^5+\frac1{x^5}$

Answer (score 5):

$\textbf{Hint:}$  $$x^2-5x+1=0\Rightarrow  x+\frac{1}{x}=5$$
$$ x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}=23$$
You can multiply $$ \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ for $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}$.

Can you obtain $x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}$ progressing?

Comment: Thanks I Got that ,2525

Comment: @HarryPotter, Correct!

Comment: Very smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion.  Let $a_n=x^n+\frac1{x^n}$.  Then $a_0=2$ and $a_1=5$.  We have
$$a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+a_n=0.$$
So $a_2=5a_1-a_0=23$, $a_3=5a_2-a_1=110$, $a_4=5a_3-a_2=527$, and $a_5=5a_4-a_3=2525$.  So, $$x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}=2525.$$